# Configure Sub-Menu button in kodi?

Tags: ubuntu, xbmc

I use mimic skin with kodi 15.2 installed on my Ubuntu PC. Now I would like to change the onclick event of a submenu button(eg power>quit). I tried modifying Includes_Menus.xml but the button still does what it did previously. Do I need to change another file?

Answer (score 0):

I am stuck in a similar boat but with confluence. Kodi does not exit smoothly for me because of which I wanted to edit the default Quit() method.

Did you find a way to update it?

Comment: Congratulations on your first post! However, the above does not qualify as an answer; should rather be posted as a comment.